# Pandas sum rows with nearly identical values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to organize a spreadsheet to keep track of the item flow.

The goal is to sum the amount column, for the items with the same action, price, and date.

So for example:

```
Item  action amount price date

socks   buy    10    $20  5/1

socks   buy     5    $20  5/1

socks   sell    5    $20  5/1

shoes   sell    7    $25  5/2

shoes   sell    2    $25  5/2

shoes   sell    8    $30  5/2
```

--would turn into--

```
socks   buy     15   $20  5/1
socks   sell     5   $20  5/1
shoes   sell     9   $25  5/2
shoes   sell     8   $30  5/2
```

Is this possible using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe on `'Item', 'action', 'price', 'date'` then use the agg function [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to calculate the sum for `amount` column for each group, then use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to reset the index of grouped dataframe:

```
df = df.groupby(['Item', 'action', 'price', 'date']).sum().reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
   Item action  amount price date
0  shoes   sell       9   $25  5/2
1  shoes   sell       8   $30  5/2
2  socks    buy      15   $20  5/1
3  socks   sell       5   $20  5/1
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Can you elaborate a little bit on what the functions after .sum() do? ".reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)"

Comment: @llssff `groupby.sum` calculates the sum of group values in our case it calculates the sum of `amount` column, `reset_index` is used to reset the index of dataframe. Here, I have used reindex which is totally optional you may skip it if order of columns don't matter. Although i suggest you to read the pandas docs for more information.